# KSQL - Non-streaming query

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Is there a way to query all current entries in KTABLE? I'm trying to execute the http request to REST api with the payload

```
{
  "ksql": "SELECT * FROM MY_KTABLE;",
  "streamsProperties": {
      "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
   }
}
```

and the stream is indefinitely hanging. The documentation says

> It is the equivalent of a traditional database table but enriched by
>   streaming semantics such as windowing.

So is it possible to make regular queries when you just need all current data without streaming and regard KTABLE as regular cache table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KSQL Table used Kafka Streams' KTable so in order to access the current value of the KTable you will need to access state stores in all instances of the streams job. In Kafka Streams you can do this using `interactive queries`, however, we don't support interactive queries in KSQL yet.

One workaround to see the current state of a table in KSQL would be to use Kafka Connect to push the kafka topic corresponding to the Table into an external table such as Postgres table or Cassandra table. This external table will have the latest values of the KSQL table.